# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb in a Gradle project (Intellij)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project in IntelliJ which I am using to control my dependencies but I am new to Gradle so I am probably doing something wrong.

I am getting this error when running my code:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://<db address>
```

the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client
    compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '1.1.7'
}
```

The jdbc.properties file that I am also using:

```
jdbc.drivers=com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mariadb://<db address>
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=password
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dependency on the MariaDB Java driver hence this message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://<db address>
```

You can add the MariaDB Java driver to your classpath by updating the `dependencies` block of `build.gradle` ...

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Apologies, just updated the answer to make that clearer.